# How to match one array to another array but saving matching elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following 2 arrays being returned from a function I'm wanting to go through Array A and if one of those values is found in Array B, i want to save the coordinates. At the moment what i've tried returns nothing. (I'm just trying to return if anotherArray includes one of the collabs

Array A

```
anotherArray = 
[
    "Jadavpur University",
    "University of Wales, Bangor",
    "University of Wales, Bangor",
    "University of Wales, Bangor",
    "University of Aberdeen",
    "University of Glasgow"
]
```

Filter Array

```
    filter [
    {
        "collabs": "Agri-food,18a Newforge Lane, Belfast",
        "coordinates": [
            -5.943629,
            54.559632
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Manga Cl, Nairobi, Kenya",
        "coordinates": [
            36.81667,
            -1.28333
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Dundee",
        "coordinates": [
            -2.97,
            56.464
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Leeds",
        "coordinates": [
            -1.54917,
            53.79972
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Scottish Bowel Screening Centre",
        "coordinates": [
            -86.6396113,
            33.6535795
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "NHS Greater Glasgow & Clyde",
        "coordinates": [
            -4.066085,
            55.797777
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Aberdeen",
        "coordinates": [
            -2.140831,
            57.118693
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "CEH Edinburgh",
        "coordinates": [
            -73.660483,
            45.456296
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Anhui University",
        "coordinates": [
            -77.8624,
            40.8005
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Wales, Bangor",
        "coordinates": [
            -4.13,
            53.23
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Food and Environment Research Agency (FERA)",
        "coordinates": [
            1.55528,
            42.55833
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Centre for Environment, Fisheries and Aquaculture Science (CEFAS)",
        "coordinates": [
            1.55528,
            42.55833
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Edinburgh",
        "coordinates": [
            -3.19889,
            55.95
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Manchester",
        "coordinates": [
            -2.275228,
            53.488028
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Aberdeen",
        "coordinates": [
            -2.140831,
            57.118693
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "University of Natural Resources and Life Sciences",
        "coordinates": [
            1.55528,
            42.55833
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Jadavpur University",
        "coordinates": [
            77.2146,
            28.6882
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Noakhali Science and Technology University (NSTU)",
        "coordinates": [
            25.205,
            59.071
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Plymouth Marine Laboratory",
        "coordinates": [
            -93.4665,
            45.0065
        ]
    },
    {
        "collabs": "Huazhong Agricultural University",
        "coordinates": [
            -123.25275,
            49.266565
        ]
    }
]
```

What i've tried

```
 res = filterArray.filter(f=> anotherArray.includes(f));
```

Expected Output

```
res = [

 matchingObject: {
     "collabs": "University of Wales, Bangor",
        "coordinates": [
            -4.13,
            53.23
        ]
}
]
```

Comment: expected output ?

Comment: array B is not valid Javascript or JSON.

Comment: Updated OP with a valid JSON and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your `filterArray` is not a valid array. You should pass each item as an object like this:</strike>

```js
filterArray = [
  {
    collabs: "Agri-food,18a Newforge Lane, Belfast",
    coordinates:  [-5.943629, 54.559632]
  },
  {
    collabs: "Manga Cl, Nairobi, Kenya"
    coordinates:  [36.81667, -1.28333]
  } // and so on
]
```

Your approach of filtering each element is good, it's just that you have to compare f.collabs, as f represents each object in the array.

```js
res = filterArray.filter(f => anotherArray.includes(f.collabs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan mentioned your JSON isnt valid. Here's the corrected format and change your filter to this.

```
res = filterArray.filter(f=> anotherArray.includes(f.collabs)); 
console.log(res)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfwcvLbn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use filter function to filter data and map function as projection

```
var filterdData = filterArray.filter(function(t){ return anotherArray.indexOf(t.collabs) !== -1 }).map(function(t){return t.coordinates;});
```